# C++ get и set методы

Tags: c++, setter, getter

В классе есть порядка 50 переменных, не связанных между собой, как рекомендуется их нужно помещать в секцию `private`, и в `public` для доступа к ним уже писать методы `get` и `set`. Но можно ли это сделать удобнее? Так как по мне это удлиняет сам модуль и понижает читабельность кода, писать эти методы для каждой переменной... Разве нельзя сделать это более грамотно и удобно, чтобы не писать столько повторяющегося кода?

Comment: Я думаю, что вам надо думать, как перепроектировать класс, так как когда в классе имеется около 50 членов данных, к которым ко всем вы хотите открыть доступ, то это говорит о том, что явно класс плохо спроектирован.:)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/121799/

Comment: Сомнительная реализация по ссылке.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , чем разное количество (1 или 50) элементов плохо? если в классе 50 сеттеров это плохо?

Comment: @perfect Вам как легче отследить состояние объекта: когда у него 1 открытый член данных или 50?:)

Comment: Да комментарий человека по ссылке существу, о чём я.    https://habrahabr.ru/post/121799/#comment_3988481   первый вверху ник  ScratchBoom

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , а если этот класс структура хранения данных?

Comment: @perfect Если это структура хранения данных, то зачем нужны геттеры и сеттеры?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow например контролировать ввод (приходящие значения)

Comment: @perfect В структуре по умолчанию члены структуры открыты. Так что нет смысла объявлять еще геттеры и сеттеры. Ежели под структурой вы имеете в виду структуру данных, в которой данные не взаимосвязаны логически, как указано в вопросе, то лучше разбить эту структуру данных на некоторые логически связанные структуры.

Comment: да разбить то можно и будет куча вложенных структур\классов это не решение проблемы, количество гетеров\сетеров от этого не поменяется. Просто будут по разным подклассам

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , я вопрос автора не учитаваю , просто вы пишите 50 открытых членов это плохо. А я вот например хочу что бы например в поле попадали правильные данные независимо от их формата. а то есть есть поле с видом dd:yyyy , если туда приходит например 12:2016 проблем нет но я и хочу если туда приходит 2016:12 перевернуть в 12:2016 и записать новое правильное значение. Поможет ли в этом разбивка?

Comment: @Disastricks free_ze дал вам единственно правильный способ реализации свойств. по крайней мере я другого не видел, новый стандарт (11,14) я слабо знаю может в нем что нибудь есть.

Comment: @perfect Если вы хотите, чтобы в эти поля попадали правильные данные, то эти поля не должны быть открытыми.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , ваше утверждение будет верным если класс надо будет кому то передавать и тут я даже спорить не буду. НО. для себя я оставлю и открытые члены и публичные безопасные методы, а для передачи класса кому то я передам SAFE класс порожденный от своего с перекрытыми открытыми членами и оставлю только безопасные методы. И сделаю я это в пару кликов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такое количество членов класса наводит на мысль о **плохом** дизайне...

Что касается `public` и `private`. Я бы сформулировал так. Если члены класса стабильны (вы не собираетесь менять представление состояния) и не связаны с инвариантом класса, т.е. если их произвольное изменение не в состоянии сделать сам класс некорректным - то их можно делать открытыми. Классический пример:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Делать `Point` с закрытыми членами и функциями для доступа к ним - явный перебор. Как ни меняйте `x` и `y` - это все равно будет корректная точка.

Если же такое изменение членов может привести к недействительности класса - только закрытые. Например, (несколько надуманный) класс, в котором есть массив определенного размера:

```
class Storage {
    private:
    int * array;
    int array_size;
...
};
```

Представим, что в конструкторе вы выделяете память под массив, сохраняете количество элементов в `array_size` - скажем, для ограничения доступа. Если теперь можно непосредственно достучаться до `array` или `array_size` и несогласованно их поменять - все, ваш класс будет делать не пойми что.

Примерно так делал бы я :)

Но - еще раз - 50 членов в классе - это нехороший признак...

А если вам хочется просто поменьше писать - ну, определите макрос в духе

```
DEF(type, var)  private: type var; \
    public: type get_##var() const { return var; } \
            void set_##var(type val) { var = val; }
```

и будет у вас класс типа

```
class Bedlam
{

    DEF(int,x)
    DEF(int,y)
    DEF(int,z)
    DEF(char,c)
    DEF(string,s)
...
```

Тоже вариант...

P.S. Если геттеры-сеттеры нужны обязательно и невелики - лучше их вписывать в объявление класса, тогда компилятор сможет их встраивать, что куда эффективнее, чем вызов - если они будут определены в отдельном файле реализации. Говорят, кое-какие ключики кое-каких компиляторов способны справиться и в этом случае :), но зачем усложнять им работу?..

Comment: Почему то все принялись переменные-члены представлять в виде реальных объектов - координаты и фигуры. а вы таким способом организуйте одну запись таблицы из 50 полей с разными типами данных. а насчет макроса - какой от него толк если у него логика одна и та же, зачем нужен код который ничего не делает?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все грамотно расписал.  Класс вообще существует на протяжении всей работы программы и недействительности у меня быть не может.

Answer (score 2):

> есть в классе у меня порядка 50 переменных не связанных между собой

Одно из двух. Или ваш класс неправильно спроектирован, или это не класс а структура данных. В первом случае займитесь рефакторингом. Данные в классе должны быть тесно связаны друг с другом, и класс должен выполнять одну задачу([GRASP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP)). Возможно у вас там на самом деле куча классов из которых вы сделали "химеру". Если же это структура данных без поведения то не переживайте, в этом случае геттеры и сеттеры не нужны. Целостность такой структуры должен контролировать код который находится уровнем выше.

Теперь о том зачем это нужно. Допустим у нас есть класс `Rect`:

```
class Rect{
    int _x1;
    int _y1;
    int _x2;
    int _y2;
public:
    int left() const{return _x1;}
    int right() const{return _x2;}
    int top() const{return _y2;}
    int bottom() const{return _y1;}
    int width() const{return _x2 - _x1;}
    int heigth() const{return _y2 - _y1;}
};
```

Как видите он задается двумя точками. Допустим спустя какое-то время вы решаете что лучше бы задавать прямоугольник не двумя точками, а одной точкой, высотой и шириной:

```
class Rect{
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _width;
    int _heigth;
public:
    int left() const{return _x;}
    int right() const{return _x + _width;}
    int top() const{return _y + _heigth;}
    int bottom() const{return _y;}
    int width() const{return _width;}
    int heigth() const{return _heigth;}
};
```

Интерфейс класса остался прежним несмотря на на то что реализация изменилась. В коде, который использует класс `Rect` не придется изменить ни строчки кода.

> Так как по мне это удлиняет сам модуль и понижает читабельность кода,
>   писать эти методы для каждой переменной

Как видите десяток строк кода сэкономил нам кучу сил и времени. Да и вовсе не обязательно выставлять наружу все свои переменные. Достаточно определить неизменный интерфейс, а какие у вас там данные никому не рассказывать. Эта концепция называется **инкапсуляцией**.

> Разве нельзя сделать это более грамотно и удобно?

Единственное что может вам слегка облегчить жизнь это современные IDE, которые умеют генерировать методы получения/установки значений автоматически

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы не понижалась читаемость делите файлы на определения (заголовочные файлы .h/.hpp) и реализацию (.c/.cpp). Это будет более грамотно и удобно для использующих ваш модуль.
А для того чтобы было удобно вам используйте редакторы кода с возможностями автоматизации таких рутинных действий.

Comment: владимир, в с++ принято на 1 объявление класса - 1 файл на его интерфейс + 1 файл на его определение.

Comment: что то ответ вообще не в тему даже.  У меня так и сделано. Перечитай вопрос.

Comment: @perfect ну да, а я как написал? Так не только в С++, в С тоже так же принято, файл на декларацию и файл на реализацию.

Comment: @Disastricks у тебя в вопросе не написано, как у тебя сделано, а я миллион раз встречался с тем что код пишут прямо в заголовочном файле, поэтому и написал. А по сути тебе написали правильно - 50 переменных в классе значит что твой код просит рефакторинга.

Answer (score 0):

Накидал класс который позволяет решить вашу проблему. Если понравится и не разберетесь в нем то я завтра прокомментирую свой код. Все данные спрятаны и минимум сеттеров и геттеров (по одному на каждый тип данных).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test{
private:
    class VarInt{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
    } i;

    class VarChar{
    public:
        char a;
        char b;
    } c;
public:
    void setInt(string var, int val){
        if (var == "a")
            cout << "a=" << (i.a = val) << endl;

        if (var == "b")
            cout << "b=" << (i.b = val) << endl;

        if ((var != "a") && (var != "b"))
            cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    int getInt(string var){
        if (var == "a")
            return i.a;

        if (var == "b")
            return i.b;
    }

    void setChar(string var, char val){
        if (var == "a")
            cout << "a=" << (c.a = val) << endl;

        if (var == "b")
            cout << "b=" << (c.b = val) << endl;

        if ((var != "a") && (var != "b"))
            cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    char getChar(string var){
        if (var == "a")
            return c.a;

        if (var == "b")
            return c.b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Test t;

    t.setInt("a", 10);
    t.setInt("b", 20);
    t.setInt("x", 30);

    cout << t.getInt("b") << endl;

    t.setChar("a", '+');
    t.setChar("b", '-');
    t.setChar("x", '~');

    cout << t.getChar("b") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну это уже перебор :) Особенно в плане эффективности - тут просто хочется сесть и заплакать... Вместо простого присваивания `int`'а - длинная логика, использование `string`, ergo - выделение/освобождение памяти... Тут тормоза будут хорошо, если только на порядок...

Comment: @Harry а что вы будете делать при необходимости обработки приходящих данных и проверки их значения в необходимом поле? делать прямое присваивание? )

Comment: А какое отношение мое замечание об использовании обращения по имени через if и сравнивание строк имеет к проверке? См. мой ответ - это четкий второй случай, буду делать соответствующую функцию. Которая будет работать с членами прямо, а не по имени с тремя преобразованиями в string...

Comment: @Harry , присваивание у меня происходит из int в int (по другому в С++ не бывает). а выбор переменной происходит по строковому значению, хотите быстрей используйте `int` или `char *` , `string` здесь для удобства и демонстрации работы кода. А если по делу то автору же плохо от того что все члены открыты и надо писать кучу сеттеров и геттеров. теперь если среди 50 переменных-членов используется например три типа данных то придется написать всего шесть функций вместо 50-ти. Я решил его проблему?

Comment: ps @Harry , если вы мне покажете одиночный метод который позволяет напрямую обратится к любой из 2х переменных-членов из одного параметра. обязательно маякните мне я бы хотел это видеть.

Comment: Поясняю еще раз. Если человек задает вопрос "у меня болит голова, что делать?", я не считаю верным ответ "треснуться об стену так, чтобы потерять сознание, - тогда вы не будете чувствовать головную боль. Тягать по программе 50 имен переменных ничуть не легче, чем тягать 50 функций, зато куда менее эффективно.

Comment: @Harry , вы рассуждаете так. человек приходит к продавцу и говорит - мне нужны красная шляпа, а продавец отвечает - нет вот вам синия она красивей. откуда вы узнали что он пишет? я вот например телепатией не обладаю.